# Python dlib - Read image instead of webcam

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am working with this example Python script from the article [enter link description here](https://towardsdatascience.com/facial-mapping-landmarks-with-dlib-python-160abcf7d672)

```
from imutils import face_utils
import dlib
import cv2

# Vamos inicializar um detector de faces (HOG) para então
# let's go code an faces detector(HOG) and after detect the 
# landmarks on this detected face

# p = our pre-treined model directory, on my case, it's on the same script's diretory.
p = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Getting out image by webcam 
    _, image = cap.read()
    # Converting the image to gray scale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Get faces into webcam's image
    rects = detector(gray, 0)

    # For each detected face, find the landmark.
    for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
        # Make the prediction and transfom it to numpy array
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        # Draw on our image, all the finded cordinate points (x,y) 
        for (x, y) in shape:
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    # Show the image
    cv2.imshow("Output", image)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

All works great, but I am trying to modify it to read an image file instead of grab the `cap` webcam stream.

I have tried reading in a URL instead but it is not liking it, anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to read a local saved image or an image present on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It seems you're asking for the standard way of *reading images in OpenCV*.**

Assuming you're running your *script.py* from the same folder where *image.jpg* is stored, simply type:

```
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
```

Of course, since you're reading the image only once, there's no need to have a while loop anymore.

Here below the full working code:

```
from imutils import face_utils
import dlib
import cv2

p = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")    
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
rects = detector(gray, 0)

for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

A video is basically a stream of pictures which move faster than our eyes can detect. So for your query, the code remains pretty much the same except the while loop part.

```
from imutils import face_utils
import dlib
import cv2

# Vamos inicializar um detector de faces (HOG) para então
# let's go code an faces detector(HOG) and after detect the 
# landmarks on this detected face

# p = our pre-treined model directory, on my case, it's on the same script's diretory.
p = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#while True:
# Getting out image by webcam 
image = #load your image here
# Converting the image to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get faces into webcam's image
rects = detector(gray, 0)

# For each detected face, find the landmark.
for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
# Make the prediction and transfom it to numpy array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

    # Draw on our image, all the finded cordinate points (x,y) 
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

# Show the image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)

k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#cap.release()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Plus it does not clarify to the OP how to actually read the image.